# How to build a library dependency inside in the library and not outside?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a module that depends on android app-compat library. I would like to have it built inside that same module instead of the main sample app that uses it.

What I would like to achieve:

```
:module
  +build
    +generated
      +source
        +r
          +android.support.v7.appcompat
             +R.java
```

This is how I put it in my `gradle.build`:

```
 compile ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$AndroidSupportVersion") {
            transitive = false
 }
```

Comment: What does "built inside that same module" mean? And what particular problems are you encountering with whatever you tried?

Comment: I'm testing the module using Robolectric 3.0. The problem is that the appcompat-v7 classes cannot be found, because they are being built in the sample that uses the module as a project.